# What is the theory behind when DELETE or UPDATE query comes in a Repeatable Read Isolation Level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, isolation-level, repeatable-read

In Repeatable Read Isolation Level, it does not prevent other transactions from inserting new rows into the tables which have been selected in the current transaction.
I want to know the theory behind when DELETE or UPDATE query comes? Consider the following example which I'm trying to solve.

> Assume use of Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) and rigorous 2-Phase  locking approach for concurrency control.

```
ID  Balance Name
1   12      A
2   18      B
10  100     C
```

> The following timing diagram, shows the execution of two concurrent transactions based on the above **Customer** table, T1 and T2, both of which execute on **REPEATABLE_READ transaction isolation level**.

```
            T1                                  T2
SELECT * FROM Customer              |
WHERE Balance BETWEEN 10 AND 20;    |
                                    |       **QUERY X** 
                                    |       COMMIT; "
SELECT * FROM Customer              |
WHERE Balance BETWEEN 10 AND 20;    |
```

> Will the Phantom anomaly be exhibited if instead of an INSERT query, one of the following SQL statements is replaced into **QUERY X** on T2 ? Justify your answer.

1. UPDATE Customer SET Balance = 14 WHERE Balance = 100;
2. DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Balance = 12;

I'm new to DBMS, So I'm very much appreciated for kind explanations which help me to have a better understanding of these problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily test this for yourself.

### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer
(
ID INT,
Balance INT,
Name CHAR(1)
)


INSERT INTO dbo.Customer
VALUES 
(1 ,  12   ,  'A'),
(2 ,  18   ,  'B'),
(10,  100  ,  'C');
```

### Connection 1 (leaves transaction open)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM Customer            
WHERE Balance BETWEEN 10 AND 20;  

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID
```

Repeatable read differs from read committed (locking version) as it retains the `S` locks on rows matching the `WHERE` clause rather than releasing them as soon as the row is read.

The query against `sys.dm_tran_locks` shows that it holds two RID locks matching the two rows returned.

### Trace flag 1200 output for the above

shows that it acquires three row `S` locks and keeps hold of the locks on the rows that qualify for the filter

```
Process 64 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 5:917578307:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK

Process 64 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 5:1:256  (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 64 acquiring S lock on RID: 5:1:256:0 (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 64 acquiring S lock on RID: 5:1:256:1 (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 64 acquiring S lock on RID: 5:1:256:2 (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK

Process 64 releasing lock on RID: 5:1:256:2
```

If you now try in another connection

```
DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Balance = 12;
```

you will see that this is blocked by the row lock held by the original transaction. Note that this will eventually succeed when the original transaction commits and releases its locks.

Cancel that one and try

```
UPDATE Customer SET Balance = 14 WHERE Balance = 100;
```

this succeeds straight away. The original transaction never retained the `S` lock on that row as even though it was read (due to lack of index on `Balance`) it did not qualify for the `WHERE` clause and the lock was released per the `releasing lock` output above.

Comment: Note that an index on Balance would only prevent the update if the original query used the index in its query plan.  If it holds row/page locks on the clustered index/heap then updating some other row to have a balance of 14 would succeed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - it succeeds in this case. The row being updated to 14 has balance of 100 and is not locked after the `SELECT` finishes. So I'm not saying that an index would be **more** likely to prevent the update as it wouldn't even have to read the 100 row at all with a suitable index

Comment: Yes, more likely, but not a guarantee in SQL Server, as queries only lock the data structures they happen to read.  It's a bit of a grey area in how to implement the isolation levels, and SQL Server's implementation tends to err on the side of concurrency.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you very much for your explanation. I'm really thankful to you.